# What kind of transformation should I do to improve my linear mixed model?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, model-evaluation, diagnostic

I asked in a previous post how to check the validity conditions of a linear mixed model I made, and here is the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/586059/how-to-properly-diagnose-a-linear-mixed-model?noredirect=1#comment1082880_586059). After additional diagnostics, I have the impression that the distribution of the outcome variable is a bit right skewed.

[image]

Here is the distribution of the residuals:

[image]

Also with the package `performance` I checked how well the model fit the data. I have the impression that the model does not fit the data well.

[image]

I should probably do some transformations. Is the information I have given sufficient to give an idea of what kind of transformation is needed for the outcome variable (BMI)? Or what other model could I run that would be intuitive enough for clinicians to interpret the results? In case of transformation, could I do a back transformation of the coefficients given that behind it there has to be an interpretation understandable to clinicians. Does the back transformation induce information losses?

Comment: I suggest you look into into the literature. A quick search found ["Statistical methods for body mass index: a selective review"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27072505/). There seem to be some good arguments for using quantile regression. I don't believe transformation would be a good approach.